# Tomcat 7 installation on windows 7

Tags: tomcat

I installed a tomcat 7 on windows 7. To do so:

- I unzipped tha archive I got from the official website in the program files folder.
- I installed the jre 7.
- I set up `JAVA_HOME` and `CATALINA_HOME` environnment variables
- I ran the startup.bat from the bin directory: the command line window tells me `"org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start"`
- when I open up a browser and type `localhost:8080` I get a `HTTP 500 error`.

what's wrong with my install ?

Comment: What are you setting on JAVA_HOME. Does the server start without errors?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you did not set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

Steps to set `JAVA_HOME`.

1. Go to oracle website, download **jdk 6 or 7**. Install it.
2. Right click on the My Computer icon on your desktop or from programs menu.
3. Click on **"Advanced System Settings"**. Select **"Advanced"** tabs, Click on **"Environment Variable"** button.
4. *Under System Variable*, Click **"New..."** button. For Variable name text box enter `JAVA_HOME`. For variable value box enter the installation path of your jre e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11`
   that's it

Comment: Yes I did it, my JAVA_HOME is szet up but still get a http 500 error

Comment: Can you post what value you are setting your JAVA_HOME to? Does the server start with errors?

Comment: Here we go:
JAVA_HOME:C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03
CATALINA_HOME:C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-7.0.27